# A shell script on linux is not able to run

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to run an shell script on a Linux Ububtu 12.04 LTS server.
Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROGRAM=./home/lab/data/setup_exp/Simulator
FILE_PART_PREFIX="/home/lab/data/pcap_partial/h_"
FILE_PART_NUM=3
RECEIVER_SIZE=4096
SENDER_SIZE=4096
BETA=0.25
UPDATE=400
MARKER=20
MODE=5
RESULT_PREFIX="/home/lab/data/setup_exp/size/size_eq4/res_"
time_part=1200
if [ ${time_part} -eq 1200 ];then
 nohup ${PROGRAM} 1 ${FILE_PART_PREFIX}${time_part}.pcap ${RECEIVER_SIZE} ${SENDER_SIZE} ${BETA} ${UPDATE} ${MARKER} ${MODE} >> ${RESULT_PREFIX}${time_part} 2>&1 &
fi
time_part=1500
if [ ${time_part} -eq 1500 ];then
nohup ${PROGRAM} 1 ${FILE_PART_PREFIX}${time_part}.pcap ${RECEIVER_SIZE} ${SENDER_SIZE} ${BETA} ${UPDATE} ${MARKER} ${MODE} >> ${RESULT_PREFIX}${time_part} 2>&1 &
fi
time_part=1900
if [ ${time_part} -eq 1900 ];then
nohup ${PROGRAM} 1 ${FILE_PART_PREFIX}${time_part}.pcap ${RECEIVER_SIZE} ${SENDER_SIZE} ${BETA} ${UPDATE} ${MARKER} ${MODE} >> ${RESULT_PREFIX}${time_part} 2>&1 &
fi
```

Then, These are files and sub-directory in the directory of the script above, called sizesetup.sh ： `Simulator size sizesetup.sh`
The permission of Simulator and sizesetup.sh are set to 755.

In addition,the input files of Simulator are under `/home/lab/data/pcap_partial`
, which are named h_1200, h_1500 and h_1900.

My problem is that I used `sh sizesetup.sh` to run this script without any error messages popping out. However, the script was not executed (I used 'top'and 'ps' commands to check the state of the script)

Comment: Try adding an echo line to the end of your script and then running it, to confirm whether it runs or not. It's probably executing quickly enough that it doesn't register on top or ps.

Comment: So in that case...your script is running. It's just maybe not doing what you expect. :)

Comment: I am new in linux and shell script. thanks a lot

Comment: But the output is `nohup: failed to run command './home/nmslab/data/setup_exp/CacheQuerySimulator': No such file or directory`

Comment: Do a `which CacheQuerySimulator` (or whatever the name of the command is). It should report where it found the copy it wants to run (per PATH). Are you sure that `home/nmslab/data/...` exists under the directory you are in, or is it actually in the absolute path `/home/nmslab/data/...`? You're probably giving an invalid path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks suspicious to me:

```
PROGRAM=./home/lab/data/setup_exp/Simulator
```

I don't think the leading dot is to be there. You might have come from Windows and heard that on Linux in order to run a program you need to invoke it like this: `./program`.

That's not technically true. The reason of that confusion is the difference in PATH handling in Windows and Linux.

On Windows when you try to execute a program the current directory is searched first regardless of current directory being listed in `%PATH%` environment variable.

On Linux the current directory is neither searched implicitly (as opposite to the Windows behavior) nor the current directory (that is `.`) is included in the `$PATH` environment variable by default. Thus in order to execute a program residing in the current directory you invoke it like this: `./program`, i.e. explicitly specifying *a relative path to the executable*.

`./home/lab/data/setup_exp/Simulator` doesn't look like a *relative* path (though I might be wrong for sure), thus the leading dot is not supposed to be there.

Comment: I am truly not familiar with "relative" path and come from Windows , thanks for your observation on my script

Comment: Take a look at [Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) Wikipedia article then. It might shed some light on the concept.

Comment: I use `./Simulator` now , but my output files are not generated.

Comment: Many *ix accounts are set up to _NOT_ have . in the default PATH (especially for superuser and other privileged accounts). This reduces the risk of Trojan Horses in someone's directory being run by a privileged user (say, put an `ls` script in yours or someone's directory, that does a `rm -rf /`, and report to someone running root that you have a problem...).